# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.models.ExampleModel

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I'm running into an issue with quarkus when using a model that is found in another module. Currently I have this structure

```
-- shared-models
|
-- quarkus-app
|
-- other-module
```

I've added to the `quarkus-app` a dependency to `shared-models`.
Then I'm using the model in an endpoint like:

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun endpoint(model: ExampleModel): List<T> {
        ...
    }
```

Then running `:quarkusDev` task it throws me the following error

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.boo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.models.ExampleModel
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.util.DeploymentUtils.loadClass(DeploymentUtils.java:37)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeResourceDeployment.buildResourceMethod(RuntimeResourceDeployment.java:172)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeDeploymentManager.deploy(RuntimeDeploymentManager.java:136)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder.createDeployment(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:185)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyReactiveProcessor$setupDeployment713137389.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyReactiveProcessor$setupDeployment713137389.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.models.ExampleModel
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

Using quarkus `3.2.7.Final`, am I missing something? Should I be adding a specific dependency when using Kotlin multimodule project?